# what are the things which can break our fast

Tags: ramadan

I just want to know that what things can break our fast because yesterday night i feel vomit but it could not reach even to my upper throat, it was happened just after drinking my last water at sehri and after few minutes i was in this situation may be because of consuming excessive water. Please guide me about the status of my fast?

Answer (score -2):

If vomiting is involuntary, then it shouldn't ruin your fast. If vomiting is voluntary, meaning that you force your self to vomit. It ruins your fast and you have to make it up.

**References**:

- http://islamqa.info/en/38579